# Existence of limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let the following sequence $$4a_{n+1}=(64a_n^3+15)^{1/3}$$the question is

> does this sequence converge?

my attempt:

$a_n$ is convergent if and only if $b_n=4a_n$ is so. Therefore $$b_{n+1}=(b_n^3+15)^{1/3}$$ if any limit exist there must be $$l=(l^3+15)^{1/3}$$or $$l^3=l^3+15$$ which has no answer in real numbers but this doesn't provide sufficient condition (it is only necessary condition). then **how do i show this in the right manner?**

Comment: You should get $l=(l^3+15)^{1/3}$, if the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\,b_n$ exists and equals $l$.

Comment: Thank you.. fixed

Comment: Well, didn't you just prove that $l$ cannot exist?

Comment: What is the formal proof if there is any?

Comment: What makes you think this is the wrong manner?  It looks perfect to me.  You've shown that if it converges, then $0=15,$ so it doesn't converge.  What else is there to say?

Answer (score 1):

If $(a_n)$ converges, then so does $(c_n)$ where $c_n=64a_n^3$.
But $c_{n+1}=c_n+15$, so $(c_n)$ does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

A necessary condition has to be fulfilled, if it is not, then the statement cannot hold. 
In your particular problem, the limit (if it exists), needs to be an element of the real numbers. 
**You did a proof by contradiction**, you assumed the limit would exists which lead to a false statement which then yields to the conclusion, that your assumption was wrong (contradiction).

So assume it exists, let's say $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a$, which gives
$$
4a=(64a^3+15)^{1/3}\iff 64a^3=64a^3+15\iff 0=15
$$
which is the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_n:=64a_n^3$. Then the recurrence is

$$b_{n+1}=b_n+15$$ and there is no doubt about divergence.